# TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of null Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Вот такая ошибка в консоли.
Вот код фильтра

```
app.filter('searchFor', function(){
return function(arr, searchString){
    if(!searchString){
        return arr;
    }
    var result = [];
    searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
            console.log('1', item)
    if(
        angular.isDefined(item.companyName) &&
        item.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1
    ){
        result.push(item);
    }
});
    return result;
}; });
```

У инпута ng-model='searchString', у ng-repeat='task in tasksArr  | searchFor:searchString track by $index'

Comment: Что выводит `console.log` для item у которого возникает ошибка?

Comment: Object {companyName: null, companyGoods: null}

Comment: Тогда проверяйте так `angular.isDefined(item.companyName) && item.companyName && item.companyName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1`

Comment: Вот и ответ: `ite.companyName` -- `null`, у него нет свойств.

Comment: помогло, спасибо, @br3t

Comment: А как сделать, чтобы оно проверялось после нажатия на кнопку?